# Drupal 6 Data Migration

Tags: 6, nodes, ubercart, migrations

I have two website with drupal 6. One was in production mode while the other one was cloned formthe production site to implement a new theme. As of now the new website is made production website and new contents (**users,products,orders**) are being added to it.

However my question is, I want to import the content from the old website database into new production one and I am facing some collisions with the primary key of it. How can I get the data into new database from the old one?

Please suggest the best way to to achive it also the database tables I need to get imported.I am using ubercart for the shop functionality.

Any help will  be appreciable.

Comment: Seems you went the wrong way, the new theme/changes should have been deployed to the live site, not copy the data back.